# Smart ASCII string representation

Tags: c#, string, optimization, encoding, ascii

I have an app that converts binary file into ASCII file. With profiler I found that I spend 25% of time doing Encoding.GetBytes() which is called from BinaryWriter.Write(wchar[]). It is completely correct since I have many constructs similar to this one:

```
m_writer.Write("some fancy long text".ToCharArray());
```

Do you have any smart idea how to avoid this encoding conversion?

I now that one idea would be to to do something similar to this:

```
const byte[] SOME_FANCY_LONG_TEXT = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("some fancy ...");
// ... and later
m_writer.Write(SOME_FANCY_LONG_TEXT);
```

but I have to many such entries to do it manually.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about "converting binary file into ASCII file" ? What conversion do you apply exactly ?

Comment: What is the difference between binary file into ASCII file?
(what do you mean by that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're creating a text file, why are you using `BinaryWriter` at all? Just use a `TextWriter`. `BinaryWriter` is meant for binary streams where you want to write primitives, strings etc in a simple way.

(Is all your text *definitely* going to be ASCII, by the way? You might want to consider using UTF-8 instead.)

Comment: Problem is no longer relevant :) Thanks for input - helped greatly.